# How to do simple CSS selectors translate to Radium?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I’m new to [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium) and I’m finding it difficult to do some of the most simple CSS the Radium way. Here are some examples of where I’m getting hung up:

1. Descendant selector. I understand that there are methods to apply rules if there is a hover on the parent by setting up state logic, but I can’t seem to find a straight forward way to target elements of a parent. For example, any item with the .anchor class will be red. But if the `.anchor` is a descendant of a `.listItem` it should be blue. In css, I would simply do `.listItem .anchor { color: blue; }`. I can’t seem to find a simple way to do that.
2. Is there a way to target a specific element, like `a` or `li`? Or does it always need a class?
3. What about the adjacent selector, is there a Radium way to handle that? For example, `.one + .two { color: blue; }`
4. How can I select direct children? For example, `.container > .ul { color: blue }`, only targeting `.ul` elements that are the direct children of container
5. What if I want to give two classes the same style? Ex: `.one, .two { color: blue }`

Comment: "Eliminating CSS in favor of inline styles that are computed on the fly" Yikes, that's a big step backward... these seem like pertinent and on-topic questions, but there's just too many here for one "Stack Overflow" question. At the very least, can you add a Stack Snippet that shows your attempts to style some code with Radium and reactjs? A runnable demo will really increase the likelihood of someone being able to answer your question(s).

Comment: @TylerH, I'm building a WYSIWYG website builder. I'm giving the user a live preview of their changes. So when they change a button color, they'll see it. That's why I want to do the styles in JS. Otherwise, I'll need to recompile the CSS and have a page reload.. yuck! I'll try to get a code sample up